# NuGet package file not found

Tags: blazor, nuget-package, blazor-webassembly, code-injection, localserver

When I built my application, the browser would throw console errors saying `Unhandled exception rendering component: Cannot provide a value for property 'SignOutManager' on type 'Birdseye.Client.Shared.LoginDisplay'. There is no registered service of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.SignOutSessionStateManager'.`

The problem is that MainLayout.razor refers to LoginDisplay.razor which injects and uses SignOutSessionStateManager which, I can tell from a different solution, is supposed to be stored in the NuGet package "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication", which is its namespace in that solution, but it doesn't exist in this one, Visual Studio doesn't even let me see the definition of SignoutManager, the method used from it.

I have tried looking for where the manager is stored, even on file explorer, but I can't find it for the life of me, Visual Studio says that it's in "Miscellaneous Files", which is not an existing folder and leaves me no clue as to where the file is.
I am considering the possibility that it was not added with the NuGet, but how could that happen?

Multiple solutions lead to nothing, among them:

- Injecting the NuGet into _Imports.razor.
- Updating the NuGet package to a previous version.
- Clearing obj and bin / restarting VS / rebooting system / etc.
- Copying the SignOutStateManager.cs file into every SourceServer folder. (Nuclear Option?)

I am a beginner, so any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So sorry neglected to include a line in my client-side program.cs, for anyone in the future it's:

> `builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization();`

which just tells the app to use the above mentioned services.